# Stuck on "Press Ctrl+C to cancel all filesystem checks in progress" after kernel upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, upgrade, kernel

After doing a routine upgrade of packages

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

I can no longer get into my system without using recovery mode. The boot sequence gets stuck on "Press Ctrl+C to cancel all filesystem checks in progress".

I ran into this issue a while back and fixed it by installing a missing kernel package. There very likely is nothing wrong with the disk. Previously the issue was caused by the upgrade not installing all kernel packages due to lack of space on /boot. Likely this happened again.

I attempted to install and reinstall kernel packages, to no avail. I also ran a dist upgrade to get the development version of Kubuntu. That installed its own kernel version, but I get stuck on the disk check for that version as well.

Not sure how to further debug things from here. I am currently logged in to the system via recovery mode, so can execute commands. Here is some info on the system:

lsb_release -r:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Kinetic Kudu (development branch)
Release:        22.10
Codename:       kinetic
```

uname -r:

```
5.15.0-47-generic
```

apt remove linux-[tab]:

```
linux-base                             linux-image-5.15.0-27-generic          linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-27-generic
linux-firmware                         linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic          linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-47-generic
linux-generic                          linux-image-generic                    linux-sound-base
linux-headers-5.15.0-27                linux-libc-dev                         linux-tools-5.15.0-27
linux-headers-5.15.0-27-generic        linux-modules-5.15.0-27-generic        linux-tools-5.15.0-27-generic
linux-headers-generic                  linux-modules-5.15.0-47-generic        linux-tools-common
```

Comment: Restart, try to get to a terminal login and fix from there. Terminal login from startup:  Ctrl-Alt-F1 (also try F2 and F3 if F1 does not work)

Comment: I already can execute commands and have edited the question to make that clear.

Comment: Try sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove  to remove old packages.   Also try   sudo apt full-upgrade   ....  I have used both of these with a decent rate of success.

Comment: Those commands did nothing: 0 packages removed, 0 installed.

Comment: You may to to back up and reinstall Ubuntu at this point.